# "ApplicationVerificationFailed" error when installing app/ipa on jailbroken iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, ipa

I have several apps/ipa files not directly from my IPhone (7.1.2, jailbroken) and would like to install them on the phone via ideviceinstall. I am able to install other apps from the AppStore archive of the phone, but not the apps I mentioned:

```
Install: VerifyingApplication (40%)
ERROR: Install failed. Got error "ApplicationVerificationFailed".
```

I know now that it has something to do with signature of the app `_Payload/X.app/_CodeSignature/CodeResources`. Do I have to sign the app again and install some certificate on the phone? If so, how? Just removing the `_CodeSignature` did not work. Or is there some other solution to install arbitrary app/ipa files on an arbitrary IPhone?

Comment: You need `AppSync` tweak. IPA installer does additional signature check that's not disabled by jailbreak.

Comment: Do you now how I can disable the signature check?

Comment: In order to use `ideviceinstall`, you're gonna need a patch for `installd`. One tweak that does that (in a clean manner) is [AppSync Unified](https://cydia.angelxwind.net/?page/net.angelxwind.appsyncunified) from [Karen's Pineapple Repo](https://cydia.angelxwind.net/) (you'll need to manually add it to Cydia's sources). Alternatively, you can copy the IPAs onto the device and install them manually with [IPA Installer](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.autopear.installipa/), thus bypassing `installd`. In any case the app still needs a signature for the OS to run it, just not a valid one.